# How to use functions declard in context provider in react testing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-context

I am trying to test a function `showModal` that I declare in context provider:

```
export const ModalProvider = ({ children }: ProviderProps) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [titleText, setTitleText] = useState<string>('');
    const [contentText, setContentText] = useState<string>('');
    const [hideCloseButton, setHideCloseButton] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const showModal: ShowModalProps = useCallback((title, content, hideCloseButton) => {
        setIsOpen(true);
        setTitleText(title);
        setContentText(content);
        setHideCloseButton(hideCloseButton);
    }, []);

    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    };
    return (
        <ModalContext.Provider
            value={{
                isOpen,
                setIsOpen,
                showModal,
                closeModal,
                titleText,
                contentText,
                hideCloseButton
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </ModalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Now I want to test this function out:

```
describe('Modal testing', () => {
   it(`Should render popup modal`, () => {

    render(
        <ModalProvider>
            <HomePage />
        </ModalProvider>
    );
    showModal('TEST', 'TEST Text', false);
    const errorMessage = screen.getByText('TEST Text');
    expect(errorMessage).toBeDefined();
});
```

});

I am getting error that `showModal` is not defined but I already wrapped the page in the provider, so I am not sure how else I could access the function and run it in the test?

Comment: `showModal` function is defined in the `ModalProvider` functional component, it's private. You can't get it outside. You should trigger it by user event. Find the element, fire the event on it then check what is render in the screen.

Comment: @slideshowp2 is there a way to just unit test this particular function or not at all?

Answer (score 2):

We should test the behavior of the `ModalProvider` component. To test it, we need a test component to consume the context value.

I use HTML [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element as the modal.

We need to find the "show modal" button and fire a click event on it. The click handler calls the `showModal` function from the context value. After state changes, the `ModalProvider` and `children` components will re-render. Now we can check if the `dialog` is in the document(screen) or not. If it's in the document, we can check its title and content.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

export interface ModalContextType {
  isOpen: boolean;
  setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  showModal: (title: string, content: string, hideCloseButton: boolean) => void;
  closeModal: () => void;
  titleText: string;
  contentText: string;
  hideCloseButton: boolean;
}

export const ModalContext = React.createContext<ModalContextType>({} as ModalContextType)

export const ModalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [titleText, setTitleText] = useState<string>('');
  const [contentText, setContentText] = useState<string>('');
  const [hideCloseButton, setHideCloseButton] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const showModal = useCallback((title, content, hideCloseButton) => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    setTitleText(title);
    setContentText(content);
    setHideCloseButton(hideCloseButton);
  }, []);

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider
      value={{
        isOpen,
        setIsOpen,
        showModal,
        closeModal,
        titleText,
        contentText,
        hideCloseButton
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from "react"
import { useContext } from "react"
import { ModalContext, ModalProvider } from "."

describe('74101831', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const TestComp = () => {
      const { isOpen, titleText, contentText, hideCloseButton, showModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

      return <div>
        <dialog open={isOpen} title={titleText} >
          <div>{contentText}</div>
          {!hideCloseButton && <button>close</button>}
        </dialog>

        <button onClick={() => showModal('dialog title', 'dialog content', false)}>show modal</button>
      </div>
    }

    render(<ModalProvider><TestComp /></ModalProvider>);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'show modal' }));

    expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toHaveAttribute('title', 'dialog title');
    expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toHaveAttribute('open');
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'close' })).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('dialog content')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74101831/index.test.tsx (11.102 s)
  74101831
    ✓ should pass (142 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   93.75 |      100 |   66.67 |   93.33 |                   
 index.tsx |   93.75 |      100 |   66.67 |   93.33 | 29                
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.656 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```